# How can I make an ImageButton display just an image?

Tags: android, button, imageview, imagebutton

I have got a cool image (fancy with rounded corners). I want to implement that image in my android app. When clicked on it, I want it to darken a bit (like a button when pressed) and launch a new activity.

How can I do that and what should I use (ImageView, ImageButton or just Button) ?

Comment: Use ImageButton and change the image background to transparent (#00000000). Then create New drawable, with your cool image and the dark version of your cool image :)

Comment: Wait, wait... how do i do that? set the background to #000000, ok. and then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll require two version of your cool image call it as active.png (clicked state i.e darken a bit) and inactive.png (normal state).
in the `drawable` folder create a Selector file for them as follows
Like : `/drawable/cool_button_selector.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/active"/> 
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/inactive"/>

</selector>
```

and then user the ImageButton like this:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/coolImageButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/cool_button_selector"
    android:background="@null" />
```

**Added:** android:background="@null" to `<ImageButton>`

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Yes, you will require two images with rounded corners, one normal and other a bit darken.

Comment: Ok, I still dont have my actual image in that image button. I think the idea is good but the whole mechanism is too slow

Comment: Problem is: not displaying actual image, a little too slow.

Comment: what do you mean by "I still dont have my actual image in that image button."? have you included two versions of images in drawable folder?

Comment: I have two versions. the problem is that the button has no rounded corners

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17307/discussion-between-vishal-vyas-and-user1420042)

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of the above depending on what your requirements are. For button like behavior, you can use an ImageButton, Here's the instructions to change the image onTouch

[change button image in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938480/change-button-image-in-android)

You can similarly change the image of ImageView.

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) getViewById(id-here);
img.setImageResource(R.drawable.my_image);
```

Comment: And what happens with that button when I return to my activity ? Then it still would be the old "when-clicked" image.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a normal Imageview with an onClickListener, the imageview's drawable will be a state list drawable xml file that comes with its own built in event listeners which can be linked to separate image assets.